# Is it correct to say "You lost some threads of the story"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

According to this dictionary,
the noun "**Thread**" is used as a singular noun.

> [4 [singular]](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/thread) : an idea, feeling, etc., that connects the different
> parts of something (such as a story)
>
> The stories share a common thread.
>
> A thread of self-pity runs through his autobiography.
>
> I lost the thread of the plot long before the story ended.
>
> I found it hard to follow the thread of the conversation.

I am not sure if I understand the noun "**thread**" right.

This is what I think about "**thread**".

I ask my daughter to retell the story about Snow White. If she gets it right, she needs to say these threads:

**-Thread 1**: A Queen had a daughter named Snow White

**-Thread 2**: The Queen died.

**-Thread 3**: The King remarried to a beautiful woman named Hella.

**-Thread 4**: Hella was a witch. She had a magic mirror. She wanted to be the most beautiful in all the land.

**-Thread 5**: Hella asked the mirror who was the most beautiful and the mirror answered "Snow White".

**-Thread 6**: Hella wanted to kill Snow White

More threads...

Suppose, when my daughter retells the story, she says:

> A Queen had a daughter named Snow White. The King remarried to a
> beautiful woman named Hella. Hella wanted to kill Snow White.

then people won't understand the story because she lost the thread 2, 4 and 5.

Is it correct to say "**You lost some threads of the story**"?

We use "**threads**" because there are many links here.

Why does the dictionary say "**thread**" a singular noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread of a story is the *sequence* of events which cause the story to make sense; we don't call the individual incidents 'threads'. You could say that your daughter had lost the thread (singular) of the story because she forgot to mention that Snow White's mother had died or the particular reason why her stepmother was jealous of her.